# Entity Framework Code First Update with Gridview

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, objectdatasource

I want to update database with gridview and objectdatasource.And I will use entity framework code first method. Can you share examples of code? Thank you.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading these for **Code First** approach in **EF**.

https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542.aspx

They both contain tutorials and explain the code.